# What is the default action for an SPF record if 'all' is absent?

Tags: dns, spf

If I have an SPF record like:

```
v=spf1 +a a:spf2.example.com ip4:104.130.122.xxx/23
```

What is the default policy for sources not mentioned in the record if the final `all` parameter is omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC7208 section 4.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.7) defines the default mechanism:

> If none of the mechanisms match and there is no "redirect" modifier,
> then the check_host() returns a result of "neutral", just as if
> "?all" were specified as the last directive.